# flutter how can i use wordbreaktext with richtext?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, richtext

I use rich text in my app.
But, i want word-break with rich text.
How can i use word break with rich text.

My code

```dart
RichText(
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 3,
                softWrap: true,
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: _parseTextFunction(
                    pharmyAdvice[index]['advices'][0].toString(),
                  )
                      .map(
                        (data) => TextSpan(
                          text: data.toString().startsWith("@")
                              ? data.toString().replaceAll("@", "")
                              : data.toString().startsWith("\n")
                                  ? data.toString().replaceAll("\n", " ")
                                  : data.toString(),
                          style: data.toString().startsWith("@")
                              ? TextStyles.h3Bold.copyWith(
                                  color: AppTheme.blackColor,
                                  letterSpacing: -0.38,
                                  height: 1.38.h,
                                )
                              : TextStyles.h3Light.copyWith(
                                  color: AppTheme.blackColor,
                                  letterSpacing: -0.38,
                                  height: 1.38.h,
                                ),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: By word break do you mean space between words? You replaced @ with an empty string. Replace it with a string with a space

Comment: Can you provide an image that are you trying to archive?